# I need help understanding this java code

Tags: java, class, oop, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

I'm following [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/) Swing tutorial and I ran across this snippet of code:

```
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SimpleExample ex = new SimpleExample();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

What's happening inside the `EventQueue.invokeLater` params?

Comment: Read about anonymous classes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: it's an anonymous implementation of Runnable class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534356/java-awt-eventqueue-invokelater-explained might be of use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invokeLater` expects an argument of type `Runnable`, i.e. an instance of a class implementing the `Runnable` interface. In this example, this method receives an instance of an anonymous class that implements `Runnable`.

`Runnable` only has a single method - `run` - so all the anonymous class instance has to implement is that `run` method.

In Java 8, there's an even shorter syntax, using a lambda expression :

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(
    () -> {
        SimpleExample ex = new SimpleExample();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
);
```

Comment: oh wow that's cool. I'll accept in 10 minutes when I can, this cleared it all up for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`invokeLater()`'s parameter has to be implementing `Runnable`, and in this case is an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) - a class that has no name and (in this case) has only one object created, explicitly a new implementation of `Runnable` interface. This is mainly a Java hack used to allow referencing methods in legacy code. In new code, you can use [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) in most cases instead, e.g.

```
EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> {
        SimpleExample ex = new SimpleExample();
        ex.setVisible(true);
} );
```

This particular code you presented will just run the code in `run()` from `EventQueue` when it's time.