# use thread to updata content of jlabel

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I want to use thread to change the content of JLabel when clicking one button.
this button will process one document which cost lots of time. But when I click the button, the content of the JLabel will be showed after processing the document. I want it can be showed immediately.

here is the code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        // Load button
        if (command.equals("Load")) {
            // set load to true
            load = true;
            // get text area name
            name = nameField.getText();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    loadState.setText("Loading document "+name+" . Please wait!");
                }           
            }).start();
            // load daffodils
            if (name.toLowerCase().equals("daffodils.txt")) {
                try {
                    loadText(tpPoem);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
```

anyone can tell me why this thread doesnt work.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on here. Maybe at least post how the variables are declared?

Comment: Assuming `loadState` is the JLabel, try declaring `loadState` as `volatile`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating GUI from a runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365404/updating-gui-from-a-runnable)

Answer (score 1):

Swing is mostly single-threaded, invoking methods from multiple threads may cause problems. You should modify your label on a special thread called the event dispatch thread (EDT).

`ActionListener.actionPerformed` runs on this thread, so instead of

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loadState.setText("Loading document "+name+" . Please wait!");
    }           
}).start();
```

You can write:

```
loadState.setText("Loading document "+name+" . Please wait!");
```

Your loading also seem to be running on the EDT:

```
if (name.toLowerCase().equals("daffodils.txt")) {
    try {
        loadText(tpPoem);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you use a background thread in that method then it's OK, otherwise check out [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). That is for to perform lengthy tasks in a background thread. If you block the EDT with a long running task, the label will not be updated until the task is finished.

If you want to update your GUI from the background thread `SwingWorker` has methods for that. Besides, you might find this question interesting: [When and Where to call EventQueue.invokeLater() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677698/when-and-where-to-call-eventqueue-invokelater-method)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface IWorkerThreadCallback {

    void onSuccess(boolean result);

    void onError(@NonNull Throwable result);
}


public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    private IWorkerThreadCallback callback;

    public WorkerThread(@NonNull IWorkerThreadCallback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            // do long task on a background thread

            // return when task is success
            callback.onSuccess(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            // return when task is error
            callback.onError(ex.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

// call worker thread from main thread

```
 new Thread(new WorkerThread(new IWorkerThreadCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(boolean result) {
         // success result
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(@NonNull Throwable result) {
         // error result
     }
 })).start();
```