# EventQueue.invokeLater with multiple swing UIs

Tags: java, swing, invokelater

There's a nice discussion on EventQueue.invokeLater() [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534356/java-awt-eventqueue-invokelater-explained)

I have a controller class, `Master()` that loads two UI windows in my application.  For example:

```
public class Master(){

     public Master(){
        aView = new subView();
        bView = new subView();
```

Where `subView` extends JFrame and has the following main method:

```
public class SubView extends JFrame{
    ....

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SubView();
            }
        });}
}
```

Notice that `SubView.main()` uses the `invokeLater()`.  My question is **how can I invokeLater() within master**?  Something like:

```
public class Master(){

     public Master(){
        aView = EventQueue.invokeLater(new subView);
        bView = EventQueue.invokeLater(new subView);
```

It's not this simple because invokeLater does not return anything.  Furthermore, because it's "invoked later", the values of aView and bView remain null in Master.  Is there anyway to invoke both in the same manner that `main()` would invoke one of them in the runLater thread?

Comment: Do you really need to? If `Master` is always instantiated on the EDT, then there's no need to use `invokeLater`.

Comment: (Also: is `aView = subView();` supposed to say `aView = new SubView();`?)

Comment: (Finally: `aView = EventQueue.invokeLater(new subView);` is wrong syntax for basic construction. Probably meant `aView = EventQueue.invokeLater(new SubView());`?)

Comment: Ya you're right, that's why I specified it was metacode; I knew I was making mistakes.  Will try to clean it up, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use invokeAndWait as you need to wait for the outcome.

```
SubView aView, bView;

public Master() {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            aView = new SubView();
            bView = new SubView();
        }
    });
    // aView and bView will be initialised.
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes a surprising amount of sense :)  Let me try it out and then I will come back and accept the answer.  

Just for my understanding, this means that aView and bView are running in a shared but separate thread from the main thread, right?

Comment: Ah, so one problem I'm having is aView and bView cann't be accessed by Master().  I need to store them as fields.  Let me play with it and report back.

Comment: @AdamHughes You either need to store them as fields or you can store them in a collections, or array which is initalised before you start the task.

Answer (score 1):

It may prove awkward to solve this problem by invoking instances of `Runnable`. As an alternative use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to update the table models of both the master and detail views. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513) may be a useful staring point.

Answer (score 0):

Following Peter's suggestion, I did the following:

I created an intermediate Runnable called `RunUIThread` that returns that exposes the objects `aView` and `bView`, so I can return them to my Master program.  Peter, do you think this is valid?

```
    RunUIThread uiThread = new RunUIThread();
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(uiThread);
    } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        LOG.error("MasterView interrupted or failed to invoke RunUIThread");
    }
    aView = uiThread.getaView();
    bView = uiThread.getbView();
```