# Combining a constructor class with am main class

Tags: java

Can someone guide me on how can I combine these two classes into one file? One is a constructor class and the other one is a main.

Thanks;

Main Class:

```
public class JHelloDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JHelloFrame frame = new JHelloFrame();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Constructor class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class JHelloFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   JLabel question = new JLabel("What is your name?");
   Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
   JTextField answer = new JTextField(10);
   JButton pressMe = new JButton("Press me");
   JLabel greeting = new JLabel("");
   final int WIDTH = 275;
   final int HEIGHT = 225;
   public JHelloFrame(){
      super("Hello Frame");
      setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      question.setFont(bigFont);
      greeting.setFont(bigFont);
      add(question);
      add(answer);
      add(pressMe);
      add(greeting);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pressMe.addActionListener(this);
      }
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      String name = answer.getText();
      String greet = "Hello, " + name;
      greeting.setText(greet);
   }
}
```

Comment: just move the `main()` method to the other class?

Comment: Move the main method from the first class to the second one using cut-and-paste, delete the first class. Rename the second one if you like.

Comment: you can only have 1 `public` class per file. If you change the accessibility of `JHelloFrame` from `public` to something else, you should be able to copy its implementation above or below your `main` class

Comment: Thanks guys. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class JHelloFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   JLabel question = new JLabel("What is your name?");
   Font bigFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
   JTextField answer = new JTextField(10);
   JButton pressMe = new JButton("Press me");
   JLabel greeting = new JLabel("");
   final int WIDTH = 275;
   final int HEIGHT = 225;
   public JHelloFrame(){
      super("Hello Frame");
      setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      question.setFont(bigFont);
      greeting.setFont(bigFont);
      add(question);
      add(answer);
      add(pressMe);
      add(greeting);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pressMe.addActionListener(this);
      }
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      String name = answer.getText();
      String greet = "Hello, " + name;
      greeting.setText(greet);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JHelloFrame frame = new JHelloFrame();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

There you go

Comment: Thanks man; it worked. Extremely newbie here. Long way to go for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply move the main() method to JHelloFrame, which is the answer to your question. However, your existing design separates concerns, so I would leave it alone.

BTW, you should wrap frame.setVisible(true) in a Runnable and pass it to EventQueue.invokeLater(). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534356/java-awt-eventqueue-invokelater-explained) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the response; for now, but it is way over my head.